# Create UserControl with 2 TextBlock in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to create an UserControl with a TextBlock as header and another TextBlock as content

HeaderTextBlock.xaml

```html
<UserControl x:Class="GetPageDataFacebookAPI.HeaderTextBlock"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GetPageDataFacebookAPI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Header" Opacity=".6" Margin="5" />
        <TextBlock Text="Text" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

But how can I use it and binding value to Header and Content TextBlock?

```html
<local:HeaderTextBlock Header="..." and Text="..."  />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just create dependency properties to expose those elements in code behind.  Then when you use the control in another view you can do just that.
Add a name to the two TextBlock's and then add dependency properties to change them in the code behind.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Header"
               Opacity=".6"
               Margin="5" 
               Name="TextBlockHeader"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Text"
               Margin="5" 
               Name="TextBlockText"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind for control...

```
    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Header), typeof(string), typeof(HeaderTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata("", (s, e) => (s as HeaderTextBlock).TextBlockHeader.Text = (string)e.NewValue));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(HeaderTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata("", (s, e) => (s as HeaderTextBlock).TextBlockText.Text = (string)e.NewValue));
```

Then you can use it in another view or control like so... Works with binding also.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <local:HeaderTextBlock Header="{Binding Header}" Text="Hello WOrld"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two plain CLR properties, or
2. Create two `DependencyProperty` corresponding to `Header` and `Text` if you need `Binding`.

[Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to creat custom control, and not use userControl:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc295235.aspx

Comment: This is overkill. This can very easily be achieved with a user control.

Comment: It's a bad practice to add a dependency property or any other piece of code in the xaml.cs code behind

Comment: I agree, it is bad practice.  But this is how you write custom controls.  As long as they are generic and work like other controls then the code behind is the answer.  I agree and would not use code behind for views or application logic.